# nHibernate, how query a parent object with multiple relationships

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate

I have a (several actually) relationship between two objects, the parent object is a *User* and the child object is an *Incident*.
There are four relationships defined between *User* and *Incident*:

1. Property **User`_`created** of *Incident* refers to a *User* who created the *Incident*
2. Property **User`_`modified** who modified the *Incident*
3. **User`_`reported** and finally
4. **User`_`responsible**

All these four properties of *Incident* references a *User* object. Like this in the mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="User_created" class="User, WebbData" fetch="select">
    <column name="created_by" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="User_modified" class="User, WebbData" fetch="select">
        <column name="modified_by" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="User_reported" class="User, WebbData" fetch="select">
        <column name="reported_by" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="User_responsible" class="User, WebbData" fetch="select">
    <column name="responsible" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
```

I want to write a nHibernate expression to fetch all Incidents created by a specific user but I don't know how to write this expression...
This is what I got so far:

```
 return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Incident))
     .CreateCriteria("User")
         .Add(Expression.Eq("Id", UserID))
     .List<Incident>();
```

but how the heck do I tell nHibernate that it should use the **User`_`created** relation and not one of the other three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works, with the direct assignment of the ID to an entity property:

```
 return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Incident))
     .Add(Expression.Eq("User_created", UserID))
     .List<Incident>();
```

Comment: it does work! so easy I almost feel embaressed I didn't think of it myself... :S
thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. I always feel like I'm cheating equating an entity to an ID value like this, but obviously it's totally valid...